# Set WIP Limit with VSTS Scrum Template?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, kanban, scrumboard

We are currently using the scrum template in VSTS online. Previously I have used the agile template and was able to easily set a WIP limit on any column. I cannot find this option with the scrum template. Is there any that this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

When you say "any column", you are incorrect: You cannot set WIP on the first column or the last column, because those represent "new" and "done", neither of which can really be in progress.

There is no difference between Scrum and Agile templates in terms of setting WIP limits. You can do it on both, in the exact same way.